# Comparing timestamp with date FROM_UNIXTIME

Tags: mysql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have been searching for a while now, and can not figure the issue with this query,

```
SELECT articles.id AS aid, articles.author AS aauth FROM articles WHERE find_in_set(articles.category, '1,2,3') AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(articles.date), '%Y-%m-%d') = '2015-06-10' ORDER BY articles.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

The query returns empty, the issue is with the date condition, because it works without it.

Comment: `FROM_UNIXTIME()` should return a date, so I don't think you need to have the `DATE_FORMAT()` function. Can you add some sample data and your expected results?

Comment: I have already and again tried removing FROM_UNIXTIME(), but got the same result. I simply want to get 5 articles, from multiple categories where the date is equal to the specified date.

Comment: I've tested this and it works fine for me. Are you positive you have results that match both requirements? If you can recreate the problem using [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) it would be helpful.

Comment: Ok, here it is. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5e3f/2    As I expect it, the query should return 2 rows, the first and the third.

Comment: The problem is that `find_in_set()` is not returning any results the way you're using it. See - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5e3f/6

Comment: At last, this worked http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5e3f/11